File System Certificate Issues with Hashicorp Consul Connect Injector
I have my Consul Server deployed as a K8S StatefulSet. I get the following error in one of the replicas:
2024-08-14T15:04:03.126Z [ERROR] agent.http: Request error: method=GET url=/v1/config/file-system-certificate?dc=dc1 from=10.196.1.7:50078 error="invalid config entry kind: file-system-certificate"

Meanwhile, the Consul Injector keeps crashing with CrashLoopBackOff and the following error is seen in the logs:
2024-08-14T15:20:31.637Z    ERROR   error fetching config entries for kind: file-system-certificate {"error": "Unexpected response code: 500 (rpc error making call: invalid config entry kind: file-system-certificate)"}

Remedy Tried: The cluster was in shutdown state for more than a month. Hence I tried scaling the StatefulSet to 0, purge the PVCs and scale up the StatefulSet back as the following error was being seen. It didn't help resolve the issue.
consul-consul-server-3 consul 2024-08-14T11:15:43.222Z [ERROR] agent: startup error: error="refusing to rejoin cluster because server has been offline for more than the configured server_rejoin_age_max (168h0m0s) - consider wiping your data dir"

Docker Images Used:

hashicorp/consul:1.16.0
hashicorp/consul-k8s-control-plane:1.5.1

